# Need help identifying a short story about a Subway in the Solar System

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a story that a friend told me about and Ι have very little info.

Ηe described a short story he read many years ago about a subway rail system throughout space and a guy who finds a robot baby while riding, and others are trying to convince him is a real child, and he continues to make stops along the train line trying to find the person to whom this baby belongs.

has anyone heard of a story like that?

Comment: This sounds a little like Greg Bear's Eon: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eon_%28novel%29.  But I don't recall anything about the child and the "subway" doesn't go to other places in the solar system.

Comment: Is it possible you've mixed parts of the story up. By any chance is it Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy?

Comment: The story I know with the most obviously rail-related title is "Rails Across the Galaxy" by Andrew Offutt and Richard Lyon, http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1032861 . I don't remember anything there about a robot baby. However, on the offchance that your friend mixed up memories of "Rails" with another story, ask them whether they remember the very distinctive cover painting at http://www.philsp.com/visco/Magazines/ASF/ASF_0622.jpg . A fine piece of art by Frank Kelly Freas, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Freas .